# Solid V Rendered issue

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Been casually using blender for a few years. Attempting to learn more.

Making a USA flag just to play around with stuff and I'm having the following issue, never had something like this before, tried googling but couldn't seem to find.

Solid mode looks like it's supposed to:
[image: Solid view w/ texture enabled]

Whereas, Material and Rendered views look like the following:
[image: MP and Rendered issue]

I can't for the life of me figure this out. The flag body is a "import image as plane" originally extruded for thickness. Currently, it is just the plane with a solidify modifier (to see if that would fix it).

There's no modifiers on the flag body (solidify was applied). The bevel seen in the picture is on the stars.

Here is the shader just incase it's needed:
[image]

Specs:
Blender 2.93.1
Eevee

Update for after flag body fix from commenter. (Persistent star issue):
[image]

Comment: Go to the material properties for your flag material, and under _Blend Mode_, check if yours is set to _alpha-blend_. If so, try ticking/unticking the boxes that say "Backface Culling" and/or "Show Backface".

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Many thanks. That fixed the flag body, however, the stars show through (I'll try to update original post with a pic).

Comment: can u provide your blend file? so we can check it out and be sure what is the cause...

Comment: Sure thing; [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkgxnd68pfjowm9/USAFLAG.blend?dl=1)

Comment: just a hint for next time sharing your blend file do : file -> external data -> pack resources before, so we can work with your assets too. Else we "see" only pink: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQAbb.png

Comment: Oh, shoot. Alright. Sorry about that man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the material blend mode to "opaque".

[image]

Comment: Woo! You are awesome man. I thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You are welcome